# How can I shuffle a vector with unique pointers in a random sequence with std::shuffle?

Tags: c++, algorithm, c++11, random, shuffle

I am busy programming a card game. For this card game, I want to shuffle the deck. The deck is a vector of unique pointers and looks something like this:

```
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Cards>> _deck;
```

I tried to get a random sequence with the shuffle function from  but I got the following error: "No instance of function template "std::shuffle" matches the argument vector".". View the code block below for the arguments.

```
std::shuffle(_buildings_deck.begin(), _buildings_deck.back(), std::default_random_engine{});
```

As far as I can see the arguments that I am using are correct, I still need to choose a random engine but that should not be the problem. So I got to wonder is it possible to use shuffle to order a vector of unique pointers randomly and if so how?

Comment: Shuffle a vector (or list) of reference_wrapper (http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/reference_wrapper).

Comment: Is there a reason why a `Card` is anything other than an integer? Why are you using heap allocated stuff here?

Comment: @JesperJuhl  I tried this piece of code: "std::vector<std::reference_wrapper<Building>> ref(_buildings_deck.begin(), _buildings_deck.end());
 std::shuffle(ref.begin(), ref.end(), std::mt19937{ std::random_device{}() });". But now I got the error that I am attempting to reference a deleted function. I know that is a common error when trying to copy a variable while there is no good copy constructor. And because I am using a unique pointer it is not possible to copy a variable. So might that be the problem? Or did I write a bad piece of code?

Comment: @NicolBolas Card is an object. I used a factory design pattern to build the card objects. Because card is an abstract class I was unable to return it without a pointer. I am a bit new to C++ so I do not know if it would be a good practice to dereference the pointer as soon as I want to add them to the list? So I would have a list of objects instead of a list with unique pointers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

std::shuffle() expects random access iterator as std::vector has. You have to replace std::list with std::vector.

Comment: Any random-access iterator will do. You can use std::array, std::deque, and std::vector.

Comment: He can just create a vector of reference_wrapper and then shuffle that to get a shuffled view of the list.